# Firestore Database security Rules: Problem with collection restriction based on array from another collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

we got some problems with our security rules settings.

Our code looks like this

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {

  function sameCompany(){
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.companyId == resource.data.companyId
    && request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/$(resource.data.companyId)).data.users;
  }

  match /orders/{orderId} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null  && sameCompany();
 
}}
```

The collections have the following structure:

orders/{orderId}

users/{userId}

companies/{companyId}

each doc in orders has one companyId.
each doc in users has one companyId.
each doc in companies has an array containing the userIds that are in the company

Only users that have the same companyId as the order and also if their userId is in the array from the company should be able to read the orders.
This is to have a double security that users cant change their companyId to read orders from another company

The first part before the && works just fine. If I manually put an Array after "request.auth.uid in  " that contains the userId that is querying it also works fine, but somehow it doesnt work like this and I cant find the issue here.

Can someone help? Thank you for your time!

Edit1:
Thank you for your responses so far.

So the query looks like this:

```
query(
  collection(db, "orders"),
  where("companyId", "==", user.companyId)
)
```

We save in local Storage the user with the companyId. Without the second part after the && the data is retrieved like it should be, but with it nothing is shown. We want to double check if the users has the same companyId and is in the users array in the company in case someone tries to guess the companyId from another company and somehow can access the data. Like this you would need to know the companyId and the userId.

The data could simply look like this:

users doc with uId1:
{companyId: cId1, ...}

orders doc with dId1:
{companyId: cId1, ...}

companies with cId1:
{users: [uId1], ...}

Comment: Security rules on their own do nothing; they only become active one you run code against them. Please edit your question to show the code for the operation that doesn't work as you expect it to.

Comment: It would help to also show actual data along with your queries so that anyone can reproduce the situation as you see it.

Comment: I wouldn't format your data at all the way you are doing.  I suggest you create "custom claims" that include companyId (more-or-less ```{company:companyId}``` ) for your users using a secure function (such as a Cloud Function), and use security rules to ensure that the companyId matches the records being accessed. FAR FAR simpler and secure.

Comment: @LeadDreamer we have it like that, but we want extra security, that even if you guess the right companyId, you cant access that data, so you also need to be in the users array from that company

Comment: *IF* you use secure Cloud Functions to add the custom claim when the user is added to the company array, then it doesn't matter AT ALL if someone guesses an Id - in fact, it is very bad practice to have your security depend on *NOT* guessing an idea ("Security By Obscurity").  Make sure the access array is in a record that *cannot* be set from the client (i.e. a cloud function manages it).  Custom Claims can *only* be set from a secure environment, so no client risk there.